# CVXOPT L1 norm approximation - Illegal value of ldB

Tags: python, optimization, lapack, convex-optimization, cvxopt

Following the example on L1 norm approximation given [here](http://cvxopt.org/examples/mlbook/l1.html), with the following code,

```
from l1 import l1
from cvxopt import normal

m, n = 500, 100
P, q = normal(m,n), normal(m,1) 
u = l1(P,q)
```

everything works okay.

However when I change *m* to be smaller than *n*,

```
from l1 import l1
from cvxopt import normal

m, n = 50, 100
P, q = normal(m,n), normal(m,1) 
u = l1(P,q)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: illegal value of ldB
```

I can see that the error is caused by the following statement in L1.py:180:

```
lapack.gels(+P, uls)
```

and diving further down into lapack.c:3651, the following statement throws the error:

```
if (ldB < MAX(MAX(1,n),m)) err_ld("ldB");
```

However, when I read the documentation on [CVXOPT's LAPACK interface for cvxopt.lapack.gels](http://cvxopt.org/userguide/lapack.html#least-squares-and-least-norm-problems), it specifically says, that when *m* is less than *n*, it solves a least norm problem.

Can anyone shed some light on why having *m* smaller than *n* does not work?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question and for posterity am adding an answer I found from the CVXOPT issues. It seems that the `l1` function is used strictly for *approximating* ||Ax - b||_1 in the overdetermined case. I suppose "approximating" is supposed to be the keyword indicating "overdetermined" but that wasn't clear to me. Anyway, Martin Anderson says:

> Notice that the optimal value is zero when `m < n` and the equation `Ax = b` is consistent. This implies that any solution to the underdetermined system `Ax = b` is also a solution to the optimization problem. The `l1` example code is intended for the case when `m > n`.